# How to visually understand any GitHub repository's code structure?

Tags: github, visualization

I am looking for any tool that can help me visualize a github repository's code structure. What I mean is the tool should be able to show me linkages/connections between the files of the repository and may be explain the connection.

Is there any official method to do that?

In general, what is the best approach to undestand the code written in a repository? (I fail to understand the flow of code!)

**Update**:

I found one relevant tool: [GitHub Explorer](https://onurdayibasi.dev/github-repo-explorer-knowledge-map), but, it does not actually work. It should, however, give the idea.

Comment: The flow of the code does not have much to do with a repository which is just storage with history.  What are you really after ?

Comment: @RohitGupta Not sure why you even pointed at `...much to do with a repository which is just storage with history...`

Comment: You are confusing me with   `linkages/connections between the files of the repository` and `visualize a github repository's code structure`.  There is no code structure in the repository, nor is there any linkage between files.  They are there by changes and dates.  So, I am trying to understand what you want to visualize

Comment: @RohitGupta, you should really have checked out the now defunct [codesee](https://www.codesee.io/) to understand WHAT I mean by visualizing code structure of the project inside a repository.

Answer (score 1):

I use Git Extensions.  It is free.  It doesnt just give a you visual representation, you can do the normal operations from within.

[image]

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood the question - I do not want a tree of the commit history - I want to visualize code flow in the current ( _or any particular commit_ ) - the file structure linkage!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [Git Gui](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

Also Git comes with built-in GUI tool called [Git Gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui),

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/67788)

Comment: Noted. Changed my answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood the question - I do not want a tree of the commit history - I want to visualize code flow in the current ( _or any particular commit_ ) - the file structure linkage!